# How to exclude holidays between two dates?

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two dates and I have to find out the number of Sundays and holidays fall between those two dates. Can I do this using BETWEEN? If so, how?

```
SELECT date1, date2, trunc(deposit_date - transaction_date) TOTAL
FROM Table_Name FULL OUTER JOIN Holidays ON date2 = hdate
WHERE hdate IN (date1, date2)
```

Using this I can definitely check whether there is a holiday on either of the two days, i.e. date1 or date2 but what I am not able to find out that whether there lies a holiday or a Sunday between these two dates. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an even better and efficient solution to the problem,

```
SELECT A.ID,
COUNT(A.ID) AS COUNTED
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B
ON A.tableB_id=B.id
LEFT JOIN holiday C
ON TRUNC(C.hdate) BETWEEN (TRUNC(a.date1) +1) AND TRUNC(B.date2)
WHERE c.hdate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.ID;
```

*where TableA contains date1 and tableB contains date2. Holiday contains the list of holidays and Sundays. And this query excludes 'date1' from the count.*

**RESULT LOGIC**

```
trunc(date2) - trunc(date1) = x      
x - result of the query
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution you've posted is horribly inefficient; you can do all of this in a single SQL statement:

Firstly generate all possible dates between the two you have:

```
 select trunc(:min_date) + level - 1
   from dual
connect by level <= trunc(:min_date) - trunc(:max_date)
```

Then use your HOLIDAY table to restrict to what you want:

```
with all_dates as (
 select trunc(:min_date) + level - 1 as the_date
   from dual
connect by level <= trunc(:min_date) - trunc(:max_date)
        )
select count(*)
  from all_dates a
  left outer join holiday b
    on a.the_date = b.hdate
 where b.hdate is null
   and to_char(a.the_date, 'DY') <> 'SUN'
```

Comment: I found that out, I was just about to post the solution that you just posted. The thing with my solution was that it wasn't even close to being the optimal one but it still WORKED, which is what I needed at the time. But, now I know that using a LEFT OUTER JOIN does the job more easily.

Comment: Working is a prime requisite of any solution @Monty :-). I wouldn't worry about it!

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for a way better solution though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if `hdate` is between the two dates you can query using

```
where hdate between date1 and date2
```

If you want to check if `hdate` is on the same day as date1 or date two you can query like this

```
where trunc(hdate) in (trunc(date1) ,trunc(date2))
```

The `trunc` function removed the time.

Comment: using a few LEFT JOINS and a number of operators, a senior colleague of mine worked it out. I'll soon upload the alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a table with the holidays and maintain it on your own.

```
CREATE TABLE holidays
(
    holiday VARCHAR2(100)
,   d_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO holidays VALUES ('National Developer Day', DATE'2013-06-01');

SELECT  *
FROM    holidays;
-- National Developer Day   2013-06-01 00:00:00
```

The rest is just a matter of a SQL statment

Scenario 1: EXISTS

```
SELECT  COUNT
        (
            CASE
                WHEN TRIM(TO_CHAR(d.start_date_level, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY'
                OR  CASE
                        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM holidays h WHERE d.start_date_level = h.d_date)
                        THEN 1
                        ELSE NULL
                    END = 1
                THEN    1
                ELSE    NULL
            END
        ) AS holiday_check
FROM
(
        SELECT  start_date + (LEVEL - 1) AS start_date_level
        FROM
        (
                SELECT  start_date, end_date, end_date - start_date AS diff_date
                FROM
                (
                        SELECT  TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2)) AS start_date
                        ,       TRUNC(SYSDATE)                 AS end_date
                        FROM    DUAL
                )
        ) 
        CONNECT BY
                LEVEL <= (diff_date + 1)
) d
```

Scenario 2: LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT  COUNT
        (
            CASE
                WHEN TRIM(TO_CHAR(d.start_date_level, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY'
                OR   h.d_date IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
            END
        ) AS holiday_check
FROM
(
        SELECT  start_date + (LEVEL - 1) AS start_date_level
        FROM
        (
                SELECT  start_date, end_date, end_date - start_date AS diff_date
                FROM
                (
                        SELECT  TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2)) AS start_date
                        ,       TRUNC(SYSDATE)                 AS end_date
                        FROM    DUAL
                )
        ) 
        CONNECT BY
                LEVEL <= (diff_date + 1)
) d
LEFT    JOIN holidays h
ON      d.start_date_level = h.d_date
```

9 Sundays + 1 "National Developer Day" = 10

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION workdays (dt1 DATE, dt2 DATE) RETURN NUMBER IS
weekday_count NUMBER := 0;
date1 DATE := dt1;
date2 DATE := dt2;
cur_dt date;
holiday_count number;
begin
if date1 = date2 then
    return 0;
end if;
cur_dt := transaction_date;
while cur_dt <= date2 loop
    if cur_dt = date2 then 
        null;
    else
        SELECT count(*) INTO holiday_count 
        FROM holiday
         WHERE hdate = cur_dt;
        IF holiday_count = 0 THEN
            IF to_char(cur_dt,'DY') NOT IN ('SUN') THEN
                weekday_count := weekday_count + 1;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    cur_dt := cur_dt +1;
END LOOP;
RETURN weekday_count;
END;
```

And then I queried my database and got the right results. Do post if you have an optimal solution for this.

Comment: A better solution has been posted by @Ben. Look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Make a table T$HOLIDAYS with your holidays (HDATE column). These dates will be excluded from calculation of working days within given period (sdate is start date and edate end date of period). Here is the function that calculates working days within given period excluding holidays, saturdays and sundays:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WorkingDays(sdate IN DATE,edate IN DATE) RETURN NUMBER IS
  days NUMBER;
BEGIN
  WITH dates AS (SELECT sdate+LEVEL-1 AS d FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=edate-sdate+1)
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO days
  FROM dates
 WHERE d NOT IN (SELECT hdate FROM t$holidays) --exclude holidays
   AND TO_CHAR(d,'D') NOT IN (6,7); --exclude saturdays + sundays
  RETURN days;
END WorkingDays;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(qq) from (
 select case when to_number(to_char((trunc(sysdate-10) + level - 1),'D'))<=5 then 1 else 0 end as qq
   from dual
connect by level <= trunc(sysdate) - trunc(sysdate-10))
```